# Tree structure in latex

Tags: tikz-trees

I have trying to get this tree structure in latex but I don't find any example. Can someone help me?

[[image]]

Comment: See second example in Tikz manual (v 3.0.1a), on page 322. On pages before you can see, how to add text in nodes etc.

Comment: Welcome @ OP! @Zarko I don't think that will work here. A tree has a single root and this doesn't. It is, if I understand the terminology correctly, actually a graph. Still, TikZ is a good suggestion - but probably a different section of the manual is needed.

Comment: @Zarko Actually, maybe you were thinking there's a way to fake it?

Comment: @cfr, seems that you have right. I can make fake tree, however, its branches doesn't grow in desired angles ... better aproach is proba

Comment: @cfr, seems that I was to optimistic. I can fake tree to be similar to given sketch, however one branch I cannot convince to grow in desired angle, Probably it will be easy to use `graph` or draw directly in tikz. Sorry for noise ...

Answer (score 5):

Draw directly with TikZ and use of tikzlibrary `positioning`:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm, tikz ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[right=33mm of a]    (b);
\coordinate[above right=11mm and 22mm of b]    (c);
    \draw (a) -- node[above] {2} + (150:22mm) node[left] {2};
    \draw (a) -- node[below] {2} + (210:22mm) node[left] {4};
%
    \draw (a) -- node[above] {1} (b) 
              -- node[above] {0.5} (c) 
              -- node[above] {1} + (30:12mm) node[right] {3};
    \draw (c) -- node[below] {4} + (12mm,0) node[right] {5};
    \draw (b) -- node[below] {1} + (330:22mm) node[right] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version using the `graphs` and `graphdrawing` libraries. It needs to be compiled with LuaLaTeX.

[image: hacked graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1.5pt}]
  \graph [layered layout, horizontal=a to b] {
    {2 [<"2"], 4[<"2"']} -- a/""  -- ["1"] b/"" -- {c/"" [>"0.5"] -- {3 [>"1"], 5 [>"4"']}, 1 [>"1"']}
  };
  \draw (2) -- (a.center) -- (4) (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) (b.center) -- (1) (c.center) -- (3) (c.center) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The final `\draw` command is needed only because I cannot figure out how to incorporate empty nodes into the graph correctly. Hopefully somebody will comment and give me a pointer to the relevant bit of the manual! (The answer may be that I should really be specifying the graph itself differently - I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short code with `pst-tree`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{treesep=1.8cm, nodesepB=4pt, levelsep=1.8cm, tpos=0.4}
\[ \begin{psmatrix}[shortput=nab, colsep=3cm]
    \pstree[treemode=L] {\Tp{\pnode{R1}}}{{\psset{tpos=0.5}\Tr{2}_{\scriptstyle2}}\Tr{4}_{\scriptstyle2}} & \pstree[treemode=R, nodesepB=0pt] %
    {\Tp{\pnode{R2}}}{\pstree[treesep=1.8cm, nodesepB=4pt]{\Tp^{\scriptstyle0.5}} {\Tr{3}^{\scriptstyle1}\Tr{5}_{\scriptstyle4}}%
        \Tr{\ 1}_{\scriptstyle1}}
    \ncline[nodesepB=0pt]{R1}{R2}\naput{\scriptstyle1}
    \end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]